# Why does it take 5 seconds to import numpy in fresh virtualenv?

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

#### Background

Hello. We write python code that gets run on servers we don't control. We don't know very much about the environment the code gets run in. Our code gets rejected if it takes more than 3 seconds to run. So I decided to start timing our code using a virtual environment, to give a worst-case scenario runtime estimate.

#### Question

I was surprised to find that in a fresh virtual environment, it takes 5 seconds just to import numpy. Can someone explain why that would be? Is there some trick to speed it up? It seems prohibitive for a basic library to be that slow.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. `rm -r /tmp/env`
2. `virtualenv /tmp/env`
3. `/tmp/env/bin/pip install numpy`
4. `time /tmp/env/bin/python3 -c 'import numpy'`

On my high-end laptop it returns

```
  real  0m5.534s
  user  0m0.612s
  sys   0m0.133s
```

Note that, for reasons that are not clear to me, if you repeat the step #4 without going back to step #1, the time is significantly less. This persists even if you run, say, `find /tmp -type d -name '__pycache__' -exec rm -r {} \;` first. It must be some other type of module caching that I don't know about? Anyway, it doesn't matter for my purposes, because I can't control the cache state of the remote servers.

Comment: "basic library" there is nothing "basic" about numpy, is quite a HUGE library the whole folder is 55mb

Comment: Hmm... I can't reproduce the slowness on my machine, and it's relatively slow. But I used `venv` instead of `virtualenv` - not sure if that makes a difference. What version of Python are you using? I'm using 3.9.7.

Comment: @wjandrea, thanks for trying to reproduce. I'm using python 3.7.3. I tried venv by replacing step 2 with `python3 -m venv /tmp/env` and did not see a difference.

Comment: Hey! Have you found the solution? I am experiencing the same problem on my Mac (I have tried conda and micromamba as environment managers).

Comment: StrausMG, no I haven't found a solution. I think numpy simply takes a long time to import in a fresh virtual environment. If we don't like it, we can choose not to use numpy.

Answer (score 2):

Because numpy is soo huge, the first ever import would take very long, not only loading all those files but  ["compiling"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files) them all into .pyc, once that that is done future import are more faster. That is why when you start anew it take soo long versus when you only do your step #4 without going back to #1

As for trick to speed it up, looking at `pip install -h` the `--compile` option should do the trick, I think...

Comment: Good idea but I tried your fix and it made no difference. I added the --compile option to the step #3 and I continue to get the same run time.

Comment: I also notice in my machine that each day the first time I import numpy that day is very slow, but the next one it isn't, maybe you need to add a step 3.5 and import it first, in order for next one to be faster, or maybe try with some flag calling python, looking at `python -h` try with the `-B` or `--check-hash-based-pycs never`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I went ahead and tried the `-B` and `--check-hash-based-pycs never` options but could not get the behavior to change.

Comment: then I run out of ideas, perhaps you need to find some lighter library that you can use instead, a quick search yield this [tinynumpy](https://github.com/wadetb/tinynumpy) and this [shrink numpy](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-shrink-numpy-scipy-pandas-and-matplotlib-for-your-data-product-4ec8d7e86ee4) or try asking in directly in numpy's repository and/or dive into its documentation to see if there is some way in there... hopefully any of those are useful...

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate those ideas and links!