# New conda environment is slow to import on MacOS

Tags: python, macos

I've noticed that on my Mac (but not Linux machine) when I have a new conda environment and then import a library like `numpy` in it, it takes a fairly long time to do it. The second time is nearly instant though.

That is, if I run the following:

```
export NAME=tmp_conda_env
conda deactivate
conda env remove -n $NAME -y
conda create -y -n $NAME python=3.10.0 numpy=1.21.2
conda activate $NAME
time (echo "import numpy" | python)
time (echo "import numpy" | python)
```

I get:

```
real    0m9.396s
user    0m0.191s
sys 0m0.079s

real    0m0.278s
user    0m0.192s
sys 0m0.061s
```

In general the first import of `numpy` takes considerably longer (at least wall-clock) time. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577922/why-does-it-take-5-seconds-to-import-numpy-in-fresh-virtualenv

Comment: @HarshaBiyani: Yes that does seem like a very similar problem. I guess it's still unclear what's going on there. I had tried the approaches they had given in there and none of them worked for me either.

Comment: I’ve noticed this for awhile and not just with numpy. It happens with matplotlib, pandas, scipy, and qt, among others. It isn’t life threatening but it is an annoyance.

Comment: By any chance, has anyone solved the problem? @sizzzzlerz
I am experiencing the same problem on my Mac (I have tried conda and micromamba as environment managers).

Comment: @Daishisan did you manage to find a solution? Thanks